# Using different Table for Authentication in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I tried with the default `user` table for Laravel Auth purpose,

Now i am changing it to the `admin` Table

So i refereed [here](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/12/changing-your-authentication-table)

Accordingly i tried to change the Table name as `admin` in the auth.php

```
'model' => 'User',
'table' => 'users',
```

to

```
'model' => 'AdminModel',
'table' => 'admin',
```

And in the AdminModel i have `protected $table = 'admin';`

And i got the error

```
Class AdminModel contains 6 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::getAuthIdentifier, Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::getAuthPassword, Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::getRememberToken, ...)
```

**Is there anything is should change rather than here ?**

Here is my AdminModel :

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class AdminModel extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface 
{
    protected $table = 'admin';
    protected $fillable = array('UserName', 'Password');    
    public $timestamps = true;
    public static $rules = array();    
}
```

### Update :

I replaced with appropriate changes

i.e.,

```
use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
```

Solved,

It didn't ended in success

I checked

```
  if (Auth::attempt(array('UserName' => $UserName, 'password' => $password)))
    {
        return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
    }
    else
    {
    $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
    print_r(end($queries));
    }
```

And it is always printing the query like this

```
Array ( [query] => select * from `admin` where `UserName` = ? limit 1 [bindings] => Array ( [0] => a ) [time] => 1 )
```

**What might be the issue ?**

Comment: The error is Self Explanatory `Class AdminModel contains 6 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract `, it means you need to declare UserInterface abstract methods in your `AdminModel` class

Comment: I overcome that, but still the problem, it is not authenticating, i am updating my question

Comment: what is your table structure?

Comment: My Table has the field id, UserName, password, remember_token . You need sqlfiddle ?