# Laravel Auth Issue while using different table name

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

This Questions is the continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27683709/3492495)

I tried with the default `user` table for Laravel Auth purpose,

Now i am changing it to the `admin` Table

So i refereed [here](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/12/changing-your-authentication-table)

Accordingly i tried to change the Table name as `admin` in the auth.php

```
'model' => 'User',
'table' => 'users',
```

to

```
'model' => 'AdminModel',
'table' => 'admin',
```

And in the AdminModel i have `protected $table = 'admin';`

Here is my AdminModel :

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class AdminModel extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface 
{
    protected $table = 'admin';
    protected $fillable = array('UserName', 'Password');    
    public $timestamps = true;
    public static $rules = array();    
}
```

Here is my Controller :

```
  if (Auth::attempt(array('UserName' => $UserName, 'password' => $password)))
    {
        return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
    }
    else
    {
    $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
    print_r(end($queries));
    }
```

And it is always printing the query like this

```
Array ( [query] => select * from `admin` where `UserName` = ? limit 1 [bindings] => Array ( [0] => a ) [time] => 1 )
```

**What might be the issue ?**

Comment: On your model you have a fillable property "Password" but in your controller there is "password" please check that. For laravel auth the password field in your db must be in small letters. This automatically hash your password while using Auth::attempt()